# Ruby inject daisy chaining?

Tags: ruby, inject

I'm not sure what sugar syntax this is, but let me just show you the problem.

```rb
def factors num
  (1..num).select {|n| num % n == 0}
end

def mutual_factors(*nums)
  nums
    .map { |n| factors(n) }
    .inject(:&)
end




p mutual_factors(50, 30)            # [1, 2, 5, 10]
p mutual_factors(50, 30, 45, 105)   # [1, 5]
p mutual_factors(8, 4)              # [1, 2, 4]
p mutual_factors(8, 4, 10)          # [1, 2]
p mutual_factors(12, 24)            # [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
p mutual_factors(12, 24, 64)        # [1, 2, 4]
p mutual_factors(22, 44)            # [1, 2, 11, 22]
p mutual_factors(22, 44, 11)        # [1, 11]
p mutual_factors(7)                 # [1, 7]
p mutual_factors(7, 9)              # [1]
```

**with this being the portion in questioning:**

```rb
nums
  .map { |n| factors(n) }
  .inject(:&)
```

okay, so this is my mental trace: first, `map` uses the helper method to get the factors, and outputs the factors into another array, and then that array gets injected?

I think the

```rb
.inject(:&)
```

is what is throwing me off. I ran a quick google on it, but I haven't used inject for many things other than summing arrays, and basic stuff like that. I've also done things like

```rb
test =  "hello".split("").map(&:upcase)
p test.join
```

but `.inject(:&)`? I know & is a proc, but I've only used them in arguments. I don't know the fundamentals under the hood. Please, take my current level into mind when trying to explain this to me =), I know how the basic inject works, and the splat operator also.

Comment: `.inject(:&)` is equivalent to `.inject { |memo, obj| memo.public_send(:&, obj)}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial quote form the documentation of [`Enumerable#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

> **inject(symbol) → object**
>
> [...]
>
> Returns an object formed from operands via either:
>
> A method named by `symbol`.
>
> [...]
>
> With method-name argument symbol, combines operands using the method:
>
> ```
> # Sum, without initial_operand.
> (1..4).inject(:+)     # => 10
> ```

That means in the context of `inject` the `(:&)` is not a proc but simply the symbol `:&` that tells inject what operation to perform to combine the elements in the array.

Let's look at this example:

```
mutual_factors(8, 4, 10)
#=> [1, 2]
```

and let's look what happens at each step:

```
nums
  .map { |n| factors(n) } #=> [[1, 2, 4, 8], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5, 10]]
  .inject(:&)             #=> [1, 2, 4, 8] & [1, 2, 4] & [1, 2, 5, 10]
```

And [`Array#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#method-i-26) is a method that returns a new array containing each element found in both arrays (duplicates are omitted).